# ACBFF not moving

Tags: stocks

Last Monday I bought stock in Aurora Cannabis (ACBFF). It hasn’t moved in over a week. Is this common for new stocks or is something weird going on. I can’t find anything in the news or in articles.

Comment: Do understand that buying OTC stocks is akin to throwing money away?

Comment: @Pete B Perhaps for most, but, in this case, it is no longer an OTC stock.

Comment: @Pete B That reply sort of dodges the question.

Answer (score 2):

New stocks?  ACBFF has been trading for over 4 years.

Barring any specific news, it's not uncommon for low priced OTC stocks to trade in a narrow range for weeks or even months at a time.  ACBFF is one of them.  It's at the same price now as it was about 8 months ago.

Answer (score 1):

Aurora cannabis in now on the nyse. ACBFF would not be an appropriate ticker symbol for that exchange. It is now traded under ACB. It has been quite volatile over the last month. Today's price range is $6.19 - $6.84 with about 7 million shares traded.